# Using Azure Analysis Services on top of azure data lake store

Tags: ssas, azure-data-lake, azure-analysis-services

This is my current workflow:

1. SSIS jobs triggered on a schedule load data from transactional database into a separate database
2. SSAS reprocess is triggered by a SSIS task.

I was trying to move to  :

1. Use Data Factory to load data from the database into data lake store
2. SSAS to pull data from ADLS

---

### Question

> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2017/09/05/using-azure-analysis-services-on-top-of-azure-data-lake-storage/

The article above gives a good path to loading SSAS from data lake. However it uses OAuth between SSAS and the azure data lake store (ADLS).

- Is there a way to achieve this using a service principle ?
- How can this be done programmatically ?

Comment: ADF v2 gone into preview recently, and it has some support for SSIS packages. Maybe you can reuse your existing task there.

Comment: I can definitely do that, but that information was just to give a background of what I am trying to do. But was interested in understanding how I can move forward with integrating SSAS with data lake without any manual token refresh.